# How can I use the Strings values stored in a main class in my secondary class? (see description for details. Java)

Tags: java, string, class, methods, extension-methods

I got a class **MainClassTestPrompts** that asks the user for username and password using an input box and then it stores each value on it's individual Strings.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MainClassTestPrompts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JTextField username = new JTextField();
        JTextField password = new JPasswordField();
        Object[] DBInputBox = { "Username:", username, "Password:", password };

        try {

            // I. Username and Password Prompts
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, DBInputBox, "Login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

            String Username = username.getText();
            String Password = password.getText();

            System.out.println("Username: " + Username);
            System.out.println("Password: " + Password);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        } 

    }
}
```

Then I have another class **SecondaryClass**, that will perform a set of actions and then it will need the stored strings: *Username* and *Password* to perform actions.

My issue is that I got no idea how to just grab the stored strings values in the main class and use them in the secondary class WITHOUT getting the prompt again. I want to run my main class, get the user/pass, then eventually run the second class and that class will pick the stored values.

**What I have tried on the second class**

```
public class SecondaryClassUseCredentials extends MainClassTestPrompts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainClassTestPrompts.main(null); // this will just run the MainClassTestPrompt which is not what I want.

        String Username = MainClassTestPrompts.Username; //I know this is wrong but is sort of what I'm looking for... 
        String Password = MainClassTestPrompts.Password;

    }
```

Comment: Normally there is only one `main` method in a system, so your question is a little odd.

Comment: The solution is to get that code out of the static world and into the instance world. Work on creating object-oriented compliant classes first and foremost.

Comment: The usual way to pass data around is to pass a reference to an object.  And that requires that you design a method with an argument list that will accept the data you want not just copy the `main` method boilerplate.  E.g.  `public static void myMethod(String username, String password ) {`

Comment: Variable names here are **terrible**. In particular, `String Username = username.getText();` - **no**. Don't do that. `Username` looks like a class, and now if I come to you and say "username" was `null` - which one am I talking about? Local variables are only given local scope; you probably want fields somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are very new to Java and maybe programming else it is difficult to explain your design decisions.

For a start, you got one design principle right: a class should do one thing. So your `MainClassTestPrompts` prompts for the username and password and your `SecondaryClassUseCredentials` wants to do something with those. This is called the separation of concerns.

The mistake is to use `main` in both, or to use a method with no return type. As `main` is used as the application entry point it would be better not to use `main` in these two classes at all -- they are parts of business logic and application wiring should be yet another concern.

So what you can do is to define one class/method pair that asks for credentials and returns those and the other one that calls the former and uses its result. Doing **one step at a time** I will preserve static methods and introduce no interfaces even though this is what I would normally suggest:

```
class MainClassTestPrompts {

   static Map.Entry<String, String> askForCredentials() {
        JTextField username = new JTextField();
        JTextField password = new JPasswordField();
        Object[] DBInputBox = { "Username:", username, "Password:", password };

        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, DBInputBox, "Login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        return new SimpleEntry<>(username.getText(), password.getText());
    }
}
```

Now your caller class may look like this:

```
class SecondaryClassUseCredentials {

   static void doSomething() {
        Map.Entry<String, String> credentials = MainClassTestPrompts.askForCredentials();
        String username = credentials.getKey();
        String password = credentials.getValue();
        ...
    }
}
```

For the next iteration, try getting rid of statics and use interfaces. To leave you something to try on your own I will only suggest how the `SecondaryClassUseCredentials` may look like:

```
class SecondaryClassUseCredentials {

   private final Supplier<Map.Entry<String, String>> credentialsSupplier;

   SecondaryClassUseCredentials(Supplier<Map.Entry<String, String>> credentialsSupplier) {
       this.credentialsSupplier = credentialsSupplier;
   }

   static void doSomething() {
        Map.Entry<String, String> credentials = credentialsSupplier.get();
        String username = credentials.getKey();
        String password = credentials.getValue();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm very new to Java and programming (Surviving in an IT world with a degree in Mech Engineering). Anyways I will digest this during the week and give it a try see if I can manage to do what I want. I know it will not make too much sense the logic I'm using but is just that I'm trying to integrate it to an existing Selenium Framework here which would make the question longer if I add this info. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in MainClassTestPrompt variable declaration should be before try catch block then it will work. As you wrote it variables `String Username; String Password` arelocal to try catch and you cannot access them from SecondaryClass.

```js
public class MainClassTestPrompts {
   //Better
private String Username;
private String Password;

public String getUsername(){
   return this.Username;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return this.Password;
} 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  JTextField username = new JTextField();
  JTextField password = new JPasswordField();
 Object[] DBInputBox = { "Username:", username, "Password:", password};
        //Not ideal but will work
        

  try {

   // I. Username and Password Prompts
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                             DBInputBox,
                             "Login",
                              JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
   //Edited
   Username = username.getText();
   Password = password.getText();
   
   System.out.println("Username: " + Username);
   System.out.println("Password: " + Password);

  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
  
  } 

 }
}
```

then call in Secondary

```js
public class SecondaryClassUseCredentials extends MainClassTestPrompts {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  MainClassTestPrompts.main(null); // this will just run the MainClassTestPrompt which is not what I want.
  
  String Username = MainClassTestPrompts.getUsername(); //I know this is wrong but is sort of what I'm looking for... 
  String Password = MainClassTestPrompts.getPassword();
 
 }
```

your code for the SecondClass will work too if you only want to use inheritance, as you extending the MainClass. But if you want to use Password and Username anywhere else better to write proper get() methods.

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting populating instance fields with a static `main` method called from another `main` method and then exposing those via getters? Let's hack my way through...

Comment: The way he asked the question did not suggested any protection for the variables. Secondly he wrote 2 classes with 2 mains but somebody already suggested the fix for it. The third and the final he extended the MainClass suggesting an inheritance.